# Is there anyway to use set of solve in lambdify

Tags: python, sympy

I don't know how to explain better, but I'm having the flollowing problem:

I create an symbolic equation, put into `sympy` solve and it shows me this answer:

```
[{p1: 0, q0: -sqrt(3)*I/3}, {p1: 0, q0: sqrt(3)*I/3}, {p1: 0, q1: 0}]
```

The question is: I used `lambdify` and `subs` to try to put these numbers into my original equation. Is there anyway for me separate these sets and use it into my labdify or subs?

Comment: If this is solved then either post the solution or delete the question

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
nrg=[eq.subs(i) for i in cr]
```

and I solved my problem :)